# How to use reference in vuejs 3 inside for loop

Tags: vuejs3

I've been developing my first project with Vue3 js.I have tried to implement vue-signature pad inside for loop.I thnik vue signature pad is working based  on ref. I have done vue-signature pad with out loop. But i dont know how to use ref inside loop. Anybody please help how to implement signature pad inside loop using vue3. Thank you in advance.

```
<template>
  <div
    class="row"
    v-for="(applicants, index) in applicant_details"
    :key="index"
  >
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <p>Signature for {{ applicants.first_name }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <VueSignaturePad ref="" />
        <button type="button" @click="undo1" class="btn btn-warning">
          Undo
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="margin-top: 40px; text-align: center">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" @click="undo" class="btn btn-danger">
          Clear
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" @click="save_signature" class="btn btn-success">
          Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          applicant_details: [
            { first_name: 'john', signature: '' },
            { first_name: 'david', signature: '' },
          ],
        };
      },
    
      methods: {
        undo() {
          //will undo the signature
        },
        save_signature() {
          //Save the signature
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull, you have some issue with your code to begin with.

- No template for you html
- export default not well formated
- List item

You original issue may be in --> `v-for="(applicants, index) in 'applicant_details'"`
Here it loop on the STRING 'applicant_details'. If you want to loop on a variable in your data juste use applicant_details.

U can also use vite.new/vue to create reproductive code and help us to help you.
Here is the corrected code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9kvde4?file=src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev

Comment: @mathew janio i have been using vite.I was wrapped my code in a template.here I have mentioned only the html part.

Comment: @sreenishcp i mean https://vite.new/vue it's a tool for fast and sharable code powered by stackblitz.

Comment: oh.ok..i will try..Thanks man.i have updated my question.can you answer this question.?

Comment: Are u using vue 2.x or vue 3.x ?

Comment: i have used vue 3.2

Comment: I belive you have to fix your entrypoint file where you register vue-signature-pad
See https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-9kvde4?file=src%2Fmain.js,src%2FApp.vue&terminal=dev for solution